# DataTables - New AJAX parameters on ajax.reload()

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

Im using DataTables (Great plugin) to create lists.

The AJAX url im using for this has variables nested at the end.

```
 "ajax": "ajax/appointments/cancelled.php?appointment_date="+localStorage['ajaxDate'],
```

where localStorage['ajaxDate'] = todays date

Here is my full datatables code:

```
var table = $('#cancelled_table').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "ajax/appointments/cancelled.php?clinic_id=<? echo $clinic_id ?>&appointment_date="+localStorage['ajaxDate'],
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "time" },
            { "data": "first" },
            { "data": "last" },
            { "data": "petname" },
            { "data": "apt" },
            { "data": "species" },
            { "data": "phone" },
            { "data": "status" },                                               
            { "data": "button" }

        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );

    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#cancelled_table tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
```

I can redraw this table when database info changes with:

```
cancelledTable.ajax.reload();
```

The above code is triggered when "Next Day" is clicked.. The localStorage['ajaxDate'] var gets increased by 1.

The problem is: When the ajax is reloaded, it does not use the new localStorage['ajaxDate'] as the date.

I would post what I have tried, but I don't have a single idea on how to get cancelledTable.ajax.reload() to see the variable nested in the url has changed..

Any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done multiple ways, one of them is shown below. I omitted some parts of your code for brevity.

```
var table = $('#cancelled_table').DataTable({
   "ajax": {
       "data": function(){
          $('#cancelled_table').DataTable().ajax.url(
              "ajax/appointments/cancelled.php"
              + "?clinic_id=<? echo $clinic_id ?>"
              + "&appointment_date=" + localStorage['ajaxDate']
          );
       }
   },
   "columns": [
      // ...
   ]
});
```

When database info changes I assume you update the data in `localStorage['ajaxDate']`. Then you need to call:

```
table.ajax.reload();
```

This will cause function specified in the [ajax.data](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) option to be called. This callback function uses current value in `localStorage['ajaxDate']` and updates the URL for the Ajax request.

Comment: So when I need to redraw the table with an updated ajax url, I call the function? Im not understanding this 100%. Can you give a little explanation?

Comment: You need to update the data in `localStorage['ajaxDate']` and call `table.ajax.reload()`. This will cause function specified in the `ajax.data` option ([reference](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data)) to be called. This callback function uses current value in `localStorage['ajaxDate']` and sets the url for the AJAX request.